# Why swapping does not occur in below python code

Tags: python

```
def rev(n):
for i in range(int(len(n)//2)):

temp = n[i]
n[i] = n[len(n)-i-1]
n[len(n)-i-1] = temp
or,n[i], n[len(n)-i-1] = n[len(n)-i-1], n[i]
return n

n=[34,45,56,67]
print(rev(n))
```

Above code doesn't reverse the list even the logic is correct still the output is same as input.
Can anyone help me with that as i am little bit confused.

Comment: put proper indentation. but first look. you are returning while loop is running.. print the variable `i` inside the loop and check if it is running completely ?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Its behaviour is dependent on correct indentation. The use of *or* is highly suspicious

Comment: @ashishsingh How do you know when the *return* is being invoked? Also, even if *return* is inside the *for* loop, at least one 'swap' would occur. Without properly formatted code we can't be sure what's going on here. Voting to close due to lack of clarity

Comment: yes, it was a guess. agree that it lacks clarity

Answer (score 0):

The intention appears to be to reverse the contents of a list *in situ*.

The most common way to do this is to create a new list with:

```
mylist[::-1]
```

...then... copy over the original like this:

```
mylist[:] = mylist[::-1]
```

However, the intent appears to be to use a custom loop to reverse in place.

```
def rev(_list):
    i, j = 0, len(_list)

    while (j := j - 1) > i:
        _list[i], _list[j] = _list[j], _list[i]
        i += 1
        
    return _list
```

This demonstrates the correct element swap syntax and also obviates the need to create a new list. It is however very slow in comparison to traditional techniques

Comment: Could you please tell what is wrong in my logic

Comment: @HARSHITJOSHI Unfortunately it's impossible to tell what's wrong due to the formatting issues in your post